# how to set the float_format in dataframe.to_csv(...) only to specific columns, but not others?

Tags: pandas

I have a frame with 6 columns with `float64` data.

```
A B C D E F
```

1. How do I change the dataframe in place to make `E` and `F` `uint64` instead?, or
2. How do I tell `to_csv()` to print the integer part of the float for `E` and `F` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option built into the `to_csv` method which allows you to custom format particular float columns (at least not as of version 0.15.2). There is only the blanket `float_format` parameter which affects all float columns.

So instead, we can change the dtype of the `E` and `F` columns using `astype`:

```
df[['E','F']] = df[['E','F']].astype('uint64')
```

Note that this is assignment is not "in-place". Python evaluates the right hand
side first, generates a new DataFrame with two columns of dtype `uint64`, and
then copies those values into `df`. Under the hood, Pandas stores columns of
different dtype in different "blocks". Space has to be allocated for blocks of
different dtype; you can't just split off a part of an existing block and change
its dtype and values. So as far as I know, there is no way to perform a change
of dtype in-place.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,6))*100, columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df[['E','F']] = df[['E','F']].astype('uint64')
df.to_csv('/tmp/out')
```

writes to `/tmp/out` contents like

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F
0,80.81297403001469,19.445657677067153,12.108345468895742,61.25250634077517,37,85
1,51.109960070270176,71.1000927186083,13.221739366008457,64.20402135661978,19,60
2,27.114372274697264,0.44017074777940035,21.090083439236174,86.57480550319143,79,98
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .astype() method.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': np.random.choice([1, 2], 100, replace=True),
                   'x': np.random.uniform(size=100),
                   'y': np.random.normal(size=100),
                   'z': np.random.choice([1,5,7,3,9],100, replace=True)})
#Creates this DF 
    sample         x         y
0        1  0.249924  0.565061
1        1  0.707201  0.626478
2        2  0.897220 -1.103307
3        2  0.818712 -0.924300
4        1  0.374754  3.138215
5        2  0.979895 -2.722585
6        1  0.193894 -0.419265
7        1  0.675562 -1.835672
8        2  0.582984 -0.304816
9        2  0.347588  0.406904
10       1  0.053714 -0.252964
11       2  0.709975 -0.412066
12       1  0.495868 -1.173759
13       1  0.605189  0.830502
14       1  0.973732  0.109461
15       1  0.389914  0.144190
16       2  0.030194 -1.413897
17       2  0.554663 -2.613892
18       2  0.644484 -0.165491
19       2  0.991261 -0.711845
#Writes Integer CSV
df.applymap(lambda x: x.astype(int)).to_csv('mycsv.csv')

    sample  x  y
0        1  0  0
1        1  0  0
2        2  0 -1
3        2  0  0
4        1  0  3
5        2  0 -2
6        1  0  0
7        1  0 -1
8        2  0  0
9        2  0  0
10       1  0  0
11       2  0  0
12       1  0 -1
13       1  0  0
14       1  0  0
15       1  0  0
16       2  0 -1
17       2  0 -2
18       2  0  0
19       2  0  0
```

Comment: so you mean, take my dataframe's columns EF, get a copy dataframe from .astype(uint64), and then maybe replace EF by the copy, and then to_csv() that

Comment: See the edit /
Do this:  df.applymap(lambda x: x.astype(int)).to_csv('mycsv.csv')